# nodejs: How generate schema.pre('save',...) unique field

Tags: node.js, mongoose, unique

I have user registration on mongoose and I need to generate unique random `ident` field from possible values. The problem is I can not query to mongodb.

The result of script in console is "ONE". That's it.
So, where is mistake? And is there better way to generate unique random field/number?

```
schemaUser.pre('save', function (next) {

    var self = this;

    function genIdent() {
        var ident = "", possible = "013456789";

        for(var i=1; i <= 5; i++)
            ident += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

        return ident;
    }

    function doIt() {
        var ident = genIdent();

        console.log('ONE');

        mongoose.model('User', schemaUser).findOne({ident: ident}, function(err, o) {
            console.log('TWO');
            if (o) {
                doIt();
            } else {
                self.ident = ident;
                next();
            }
        });

    }

    doIt();

});
```

Comment: You can only call `mongoose.model('User', schemaUser)` once because it defines the schema for the model.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are just generating ident, but not putting it into your MongoDB, and trying to find it in there before you save it in there...

to be able to access a document with that ident you need to save it first.

try putting console.log(err) to see what error is returned

Comment: thank you for answering. as i said, line `console.log('TWO');` is not reachable.

Comment: i tried running your code and it is actually going into the 'else' part inside the callback function for the search. maybe it is not printing 'TWO' because it is going inside the if? since Node is asynchronous, it is possible. try putting only console.log inside 'if' and inside 'else'. see what it prints